# Загрузка 3D моделей в openGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 3d, загрузка

Хочу научиться загружать и отрисововать 3D модели C++, OpenGL 4. Есть библиотека Assimp но мне крайне не нравится используемая там библиотека загрузки текстур DevIL. Есть ли альтернатива библиотеки assimp. или может у кого то есть пример где вместо DevIL используется freeimage или SOIL или еще какая то библиотека. В крайнем случаи возможно ли в Visual Studio C++ сделать так чтобы возле исполняемого файла не светился файл с названием DevIL.dll Как вшить его содержимое  в программу.

Приоритет

1. Использовать Assimp но без библиотеки DevIL
2. Использовать не Assimp но что то другое.
3. Вшыть содержимое DevIL.dll в програму (Кажется это называется статистическая линкировка).

**Пришёл к решению что незачем загружать модэли в стандартных форматах, программа для моделирования блендер позволяет написать скрипт для экспорта самому, в таком формате в котором вам будит удобно потом импортировать, соответствино можно экспортировать не только модэль но и анимацию в таком формате как вам будет удобно**
 [вот открыл вопрос по этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/824322/blender-3d-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-vbo-%D0%B8-ibo-ebo-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-python).

Comment: Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: ... Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.*

Comment: По моему я не спрашивал "где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию" я спрашивал какие есть для конкретной задачи.

Comment: Тут традиция такая, что надо написать в стиле "я вот попытался так-то и так-то сделать, не выходит". Тогда может ответят, что нужно применить такую-то библиотеку.

Comment: Возможно так как я переписал подойдет?

Comment: Лучше, но желательно задавать один конкретный вопрос (на другие открывать новый). Также стоит описать, почему не подходит DevIL, и не спрашивать открытым текстом какие есть альтернативы. Т.е. написать, что при использовании DevIL такие-то проблемы, которые решить не удается.

Comment: DevIL Переводится как Дьявол. Я не хочу чтобы в папке с моими разработками всегда лежал файл с таким именем. Это единственная причина, не уверен что в описании ее стоит упоминать.

Comment: Понятно. Возможно найдутся специалисты по вопросу именования файлов.

Comment: Предлагаю обратиться с Вашей проблемой непосредственно к разработчикам. Например, Вы можете создать [issue в репозитории](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues)

Comment: Помню давно у меня на форумах был ник alexxx666, встречался я с девушкой, которая занималась реставрированием картин и в большей степени икон. И она хотела найти людей, которым нужно иконы реставрировать. Моя помощь поиска в сети, не смотря на все гигантские усилия, конечно же, провалилась с треском :D

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка, DevIL — это *Developer's Image Library*. Название DIL [было уже занято](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIL), поэтому «Developer» был сокращён до [общепринятого](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dev#Noun) *dev*. Так что все совпадения непредумышленны.

Comment: Спасибо. я и так знал как оно расшифровывается но думал что именно такое название предумышленное.  это догадки или заявление авторов библиотеки? Если всё так, то приоритет №1 использовать DevIL Но спрятать от глаз пользоватилей Devil.DLL . Почему они не оставили название OpenIL.

Comment: Только что открыл их сайт http://openil.sourceforge.net/ Логотип говорит сам за себя, что название осмыслено предумышленное именно дь'явол.